# Copy data from one table to another existing table combined by calculated variable and specific columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The scenario is as described in the following steps (this is only an example to illustrate the problem)

1. There are two tables in the database (user_1, post_1) - no real relation between them

user_1 contains the following fields:

```
  id VARCHAR,   
  name VARCHAR,  
  address TEXT,  
  phone_number VARCHAR,  
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

post_1 contains the following fields:

```
  id VARCHAR,   
  user_id VARCHAR,  
  title VARCHAR,  
  body TEXT,  
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

2. Suppose I added the following data to the two tables above:

   ```
    INSERT INTO user_1(id, name, address, phone_number) VALUES ('first_u', 'avi', 'some address', '05488789906');

    INSERT INTO post_1(id, user_id, title, body) VALUES ('first_p', 'first_u', 'new post', 'This is a good one!');
   ```
3. Now I've created new tables with few changes and with a link between them:

user_2 contains the following fields:

```
  id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),   
  name VARCHAR,  
  address TEXT,  
  phone_number VARCHAR,  
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

post_2 contains the following fields:

```
  id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),   
  user_id uuid,  
  title VARCHAR,  
  body TEXT,  
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user_2(id)
```

4. Now the problem is with the copy of the data to the two new tables with the real link (foreign key) between them.
   I will explain - it is divided into few parts:

a. Count the number of rows in the user_1 table (I've created a function for that):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rowsnumber() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
numberOfRows integer;
BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numberOfRows FROM (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM user_1
            ) t;
            
RETURN numberOfRows;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

b. Go through the function result in the for loop and do the following:

- (b.1) Extract the row number x according to the current index in the for loop (can achieve this by using limit and offset) from user_1 table.
- (b.2) Insert the row data into the user_2 table.
- (b.3) Extract the newly created uuid and save it in a parameter.
- (b.4) Retrieve the appropriate row from the post_1 table according to the id column of the current row stored in the user_id column of the post_1 table.
- (b.5) Insert the appropriate data of the row that we extracted in stage (b.4) into the post_2 table BUT with the user_id that we extracted in step (b.3) so that there is a real relationship between the post_2 table and the user_2 table.

I would greatly appreciate any help - if someone could write the query I would need to run to solve this problem.
Many thanks.

Comment: Why is there a need for two pairs of tables to start with?

Comment: This is just an example of the problem I am trying to solve.
Our system is bigger with more tables the reason we do this is a kind of refactoring to the tables 
(These are not the real tables and not the real data - but the problem is the same)
We need to copy data from existing tables to refactoring models.

Comment: In `user_1` and `post_1` are the `id` and the `user_id` the "FK" between them? Otherwise if there is no relationship between them I can't see how you can create anything but a random one.

Comment: It's FK but without validation of the database, meaning the column is not defined as real FK.
I will explain - our system is divided into different serivces, each serivce has its own database, but there are relationships between those services
and since they are in different databases, it is not possible to link them - so we make sure that the data that is entered is correct, but not by database validation. Now we merge the database into one database and create relationships between them.
And the problem is copying the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts I was able to implement the function that would answer the question - according to the steps I described above.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertToTables() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
numOfRowsInTable integer := rowsnumber();
newRow record;
userUUIDRow record;
postRow record;
BEGIN
         for r in 0..numOfRowsInTable-1
         loop
           SELECT * INTO newRow FROM user_1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET r;
           INSERT INTO user_2(name, address, phone_number) SELECT newRow.name,newRow.address, newRow.phone_number ;
           SELECT * INTO userUUIDRow FROM user_2 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1;
           SELECT * INTO postRow FROM post_1 WHERE user_id = newRow.id;
           INSERT INTO post_2(user_id, title, body) SELECT userUUIDRow.id, postRow.title, postRow.body;
         end loop;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: How is the function going to access `user_1`/`post_1` and `user_2`/`post_2` when they exist in different databases? This function exists in whatever database it is created in and does not have access to  `SQLAlchemy` and it's multiple connections.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver so what you suggest ?

Comment: I suggest a new question that details what you are trying to do to include: 1) That you are working with SQLAlchemy/Alembic. 2) That you are creating new databases and trying to transfer data  from one database to another while modifying said data. 3) Whether any of the data is currently being transferred in the migration? 4) Whether you have installed either the `postgres_fdw` or dblink` extensions? 5) Some idea of the number of tables and the size of the data sets involved? This would be a good start and any other relevant information you can think of would be helpful.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The question is perfectly fine, I asked about the implementation of a function that performs a copy from tables that do not have a relation between them to two new ones that do.
I added the answer according to the algorithm I wrote above - and it works great.
During the conversation, other things came up that are related to another new question, how to copy from one db to another db.
I'm not sure that you can't connect to each db separately with a different connection, I need to check that.
In any case, regarding dblink, it seems fine to me.

Comment: Another option is to copy all the tables as is to the new db with a dump, and add a suffix to each table for example "_todelete" and then work on the same db - it will work great with the function I wrote above and finally delete the tables

Comment: Since you refuse to acknowledge reality there is not much I can do for you.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The reality you are talking about is a bit distorted. you are more then welcome to look at the things I wrote above and perhaps learn from the answer.